# How to solve error with syncing PostgreSQL with Vercel

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a database using `PostgreSQL` but the published site is Vercel and when deploying for production is gives the error below. The error doesn't happen for `Heroku`

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "123.456.789.102", user "example_user", database "example_db", SSL off`

How do I solve this error, thank you. I have checked Google results aren't really helpful

Comment: Doesn't seem like this Vercel (whatever that is) is properly set up for postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer out. It was just not to use Heroku but instead I used a service called `ElephantSQL` and used the details and it worked perfectly well

Answer (score 0):

You can't not authenticate as HBA stands for **host-based authentication**.
That's because your host is "123.456.789.102"..

Seems like you need to fix .env

```
DATABASE_NAME=db_name
DATABASE_HOST=DATABASE_URL obtained from heroku
DATABASE_USER=db_user that usually default to postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=your_password
DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

And when locally you are fine, change Vercel Environment variables according to them as well as *'vercelignoring'* your .env file.

Vercel is serverless, it is immutable (nothing meant to change after deployment), so it has limited support for databases. The solution is, as in case of OP, using external database hosting. ElephantSQL is fine, but somewhat expensive after some time, while AWS RDS free tier offers 20GB of storage.

I've personally deployed Laravel app to Vercel using *vercel-php* & linked to AWS RDS PostgreSQL. Officially it seems like neither Laravel nor AWS RDS are supported.